# loop depending on number of days

Tags: java, loops, counter

I'm making a rest call to update these 3 fields, which field to update is decided if that field is not there in the hash map, and by default it updates "AA"

Every time I make a call a counter is also increased on server. so after 3 runs,all fields are on server and it's always updating "AA", because it's default, now I want the field to update be selected by the counter. So the flow continues as AA,BB,CC - AA,BB,CC - AA,BB,CC .How?

```
    //on 1st update call,it updates AA and Counter is set to =1
    //2nd update call,it update BB = Counter is set to =2
    //3rd update call,it update CC = Counter is set to =3
    //4th update call,it update AA = Counter is set to =4
    //5th update call,it update AA = Counter is set to =5
    //6th update call,it update AA = Counter is set to =6

 if (fieldValues.containsKey("COUNTER")) {
            counter= fieldValues.get("COUNTER");
 }// how can we use this counter to select the next field

 HashMap<String, String> fieldValues = [{key,value},{key,value},{key,value}......]
 String [] FieldsToUpdate = ["AA","BB","CC"];
 String xxxFieldToUpdate = FieldsToUpdate[0];// so default is "AA"

 for(String Field : FieldsToUpdate){
        if(!fieldValues.containsKey(Field)){
            xxxFieldToUpdate = Field.trim();
            break;
        }
  }
  // Solved by calling a new method which reset the Iterator //

  String fieldToUpdate = "";
  counter= fieldValues.get("COUNTER");
  Iterator it = fieldsToUpdate.iterator();
  for(int i=0; i<counter; i++) {
  if(!it.hasNext())  // if you are at the end of the list reset iterator
    it = fieldsToUpdate.iterator();
    String res = it.next().toString();
    fieldToUpdate = res;
  }
  return fieldToUpdate;
```

Comment: I solved my problem, Please see my Edit on the original question. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

use a different FOR loop maybe, like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
{
if(!fieldValues.containsKey(FieldsToUpdate[i])){
            xxxFieldToUpdate = FieldsToUpdate[i].trim();
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I solved my problem using a similar thought

Answer (score 0):

// Solved by calling a new method which reset the Iterator //

```
String fieldToUpdate = "";
counter= fieldValues.get("COUNTER");
Iterator it = fieldsToUpdate.iterator();
  for(int i=0; i<counter; i++) {
   if(!it.hasNext())  // if you are at the end of the list reset iterator
     it = fieldsToUpdate.iterator();
     String res = it.next().toString();
   fieldToUpdate = res;
 }
 return fieldToUpdate;
```